# How can I shallow copy a part of list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, shallow-copy

I want to shallow copy a part of list, for example:

```
original_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

And I want to copy a part of it

```
list2 = original_list[0:2]
list2[0] = 10
```

wanted output:

```
original_list = [10, 1, 2, 3]
```

But slice only give a new list, Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: A possible solution is just using an offset.

Comment: You're working with a flat list of integers -- shallow and deep copy are the same.

Comment: did you try re-assigning the slice values to the original list? That's should do the trick instead of taking a new list.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace part of the original list after list2 has changed. Would that help?

```
original_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
list2 = original_list [0:2]
list2 [0] = 10
original_list [0:2] = list2
print (original_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use Numpy array as below:

```py
import numpy as np # Use this lib

original_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
original_list = np.array(original_list) # Add this line

list2 = original_list[0:2]
list2[0] = 10

original_list = list(original_list) # Add this line
print(original_list)
```